# WPF - Binding the DataContext of a DataGrid to DataTable

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, datatable, datagrid

I have a `DataGrid` in my WPF window. I bind its `DataContext` to a `System.Data.DataTable`. When I construct and fill my `DataTable`, the `DataGrid` updates and works perfectly. Now I want to find some elements in my `DataTable` and highlight their associated cells in the `DataGrid`. How can I do this using the MVVM pattern? What other property of the `DataGrid` I should bind in order to achieve this?

I have been googling for two hours and so far I got nothing. Any hints would be appreciated.

Comment: Downvoting without explanation usually makes people curse.

Comment: Cursing will not help, maybe adding a small [MCVE] where users can expand on might...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main problem was with the binding. One shall not bind the **`DataContext`** of a `DataGrid` to a `DataTable`. The better way is to bind its `ItemsSource` to the `DataTable`. Although the result would appear the same.

Secondly, abiding to the MVVM pattern is sometimes really painful and seems unnecessarily complicated. It seems [there is no harm](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20524980/5358284) in doing some works programmatically.

And finally, [this great answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15135155/5358284) helped me a lot. I refer the future readers with the same issues to that.