# Load Datagrid in MVVM with list of custom objects in runtime, disabling certain cells

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, datagrid

**I have two problems here:**

(1) Loading Datagrid in MVVM pattern with a list of custom objects in runtime, and
(2) Disabling certain cells within a row of Datagrid, and not for every row

I have a custom object class that looks like this:

```
public class Cell
{
    public string Ref { get; set; }
    public string Value { get; set; }
    public bool IsEnabled { get; set; }
}

public class Row : List<Cell>
{
   public List<Cell> Cells { get; set; }
}
```

And load in runtime a collection like this:

```
var Items = new ObservableCollection<Row>
{
   new Row() { new Cell { Ref = Ref1, Value = "1a", IsEnabled = true }, new Cell { Ref = Ref2, Value = "1b" }, new Cell { Ref = Ref3, Value = "1c", IsEnabled = true }  },
   new Row() { new Cell { Ref = Ref1, Value = "2a", IsEnabled = true }, new Cell { Ref = Ref2, Value = "2b", IsEnabled = true }, new Cell { Ref = Ref3, Value = "2c" }  },
   new Row() { new Cell { Ref = Ref1, Value = "3a" }, new Cell { Ref = Ref2, Value = "3b" }, new Cell { Ref = Ref3, Value = "3c" }  },
   new Row() { new Cell { Ref = Ref1, Value = "4a" }, new Cell { Ref = Ref2, Value = "4b" }, new Cell { Ref = Ref3, Value = "4c" }  },
   new Row() { new Cell { Ref = Ref1, Value = "5a" }, new Cell { Ref = Ref2, Value = "5b" }, new Cell { Ref = Ref3, Value = "5c" }  },
   new Row() { new Cell { Ref = Ref1, Value = "6a" }, new Cell { Ref = Ref2, Value = "6b" }, new Cell { Ref = Ref3, Value = "6c" }  },
   new Row() { new Cell { Ref = Ref1, Value = "7a" }, new Cell { Ref = Ref2, Value = "7b" }, new Cell { Ref = Ref3, Value = "7c" }  },
   new Row() { new Cell { Ref = Ref1, Value = "8a" }, new Cell { Ref = Ref2, Value = "8b" }, new Cell { Ref = Ref3, Value = "8c" }  }
};
```

In some other examples I saw and tested, the object `Row` has a defined set of properties and these are taken by `DataGrid` in the `xaml` binding, but in my case quantity of cells in a row will be defined on runtime and i want to use my cell property "IsEnabled" to tell DataGrid to enable/disable the cell.

How can i achieve this?
Thanks in advance for any help

Comment: @Sinatr: I would like to keep tight to MVVM and write as less code as possible related to my view. With the approach shown at that link, seems to me that i would have to write this code in the `xaml.cs` code-behind, which i strongly try to avoid. I expected there was any kind of `xaml` code i could set in the view to avoid coding this part in `c#`, is there?

Comment: See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7836147/1997232), you only need to add binding of `Value` to `IsEnabled` property, which you already provided.

Comment: @Sinatr in order to manage going testing this part i firstly need to know how to do my question-part (1)... any suggestion?

Comment: *"to do my question-part (1)... any suggestion?"* - you can serialize/deserialize `List<Row>` ([into json-file](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9110724/1997232), xaml or whatever) or use database (e.g. sqlite).

Comment: @Sinatr could you please give a solution with an example i could test?